# Error sending image from file with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-2.7, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a problem sending photo from file with [python telegram bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot).
It is working great with a picture URL but not when trying to send a file from disk.

#### Steps to reproduce

`bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=open('/mydir/log.jpg', 'rb'))`

**getting error:**

`*** BadRequest: Url host is empty`

#### Configuration

- OS: Osx
- Python: 2.7 python
- -m telegram

  - _python-telegram-bot 8.0
  - certifi 2017.07.27.1
  - future 0.16.0
  - Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]_

*According to the doc we can pass file from disk* : 
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#post-an-image-file-from-disk

Answer (score 4):

Problem was with the path of the photo that was in unicode.

```
photo = open(('/mydir/log.jpg').encode('utf-8'), 'rb')
bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, photo=photo)
```

In the _ method of [telegram.inputfile](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/files/inputfile.py) if you don't send a fully unicode form, the join make UnicodeDecodeError.